# gradle maven publish Pom using kotlin-dsl

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a multiplatform kotlin library project that publishes to maven and have been updating to the kotlin 1.3 multiplatform model and kotlin-dsl

The previous groovy gradle script has a modifyPom block, and i found an [example here](https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr-kotlin/blob/master/build.gradle.kts).  However as soon as I add

```
val modifyPom : Closure<*> by ext

modifyPom(closureOf<MavenPom> {
   // pom code in here
})
```

I get the same result no matter what is in the pom data, which is that the call of the modifyPom groovy closure breaks the build with a very vague error:

```
Build file '<path>\build.gradle.kts' line: 47
Open File
```

In other words the line number of the call of modifyPom groovy Closure, but nothing about the actual error.

I am using Gradle 5.0. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

So - in Groovy I had this block for configuring POMs, and it worked just fine:

```
    project.publishing.publications.forEach { publication ->
        publication.pom.withXml {
            def root = asNode()
            root.appendNode("name", "libui")
            root.appendNode("description", "Kotlin/Native interop to libui: a portable GUI library")
            root.appendNode("url", POM_SCM_URL)
            root.children().last() + {
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name "MIT License"
                        url POM_SCM_URL
                        distribution "repo"
                    }
                }
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id "msink"
                        name "Mike Sinkovsky"
                        email "msink@permonline.ru"
                    }
                }
                scm {
                    url POM_SCM_URL
                    connection POM_SCM_CONNECTION
                    developerConnection POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And how to convert it to Kotlin DSL?

Edit:
Well, was answered in https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/2372
In Gradle Kotlin DSL it becomes:

```
project.publishing.publications.withType<MavenPublication>().forEach { publication ->
    with(publication.pom) {
        withXml {
            val root = asNode()
            root.appendNode("name", "libui")
            root.appendNode("description", "Kotlin/Native interop to libui: a portable GUI library")
            root.appendNode("url", POM_SCM_URL)
        }

        licenses {
            license {
                name.set("MIT License")
                url.set(POM_SCM_URL)
                distribution.set("repo")
            }
        }
        developers {
            developer {
                id.set("msink")
                name.set("Mike Sinkovsky")
                email.set("msink@permonline.ru")
            }
        }
        scm {
            url.set(POM_SCM_URL)
            connection.set(POM_SCM_CONNECTION)
            developerConnection.set(POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Kotlin DSL block. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was fixed by changing the definition of modifyPom to

```
val modifyPom : Closure<MavenPom> by ext
```

That fixed the original problem as posted, and the pom is now being modified.  If anyone needs help, add a comment and hopefully I will notice